# OkHttpClient POST request fails when Request body size beyond certain limit

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

I am making a sequence of POST requests with each subsequent request passing the next token received the previous response in the request body of the new request. I am noticing that if POST HTTP request body size is beyond a certain limit, the request times out after certain number of requests in the sequence. Typical request body size is about 14KB. With OkHttpClient event listener I notice that (for the failing call)

```
override fun requestBodyStart(call: Call)
```

is invoked but not

```
override fun requestBodyEnd(call: Call, byteCount: Long)
```

Instead `override fun requestFailed(call: Call, ioe: IOException)` is called with Socket timeout exception.

It works if make this call before each request (but looks like a hack)

```
okHttpClient.connectionPool.evictAll()
```

Not sure if OkHTTPClient maintains some state within. Charles is showing Failure status with `IO: Stream cancelled by CLIENT` message.

I am using

```
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.3"
```

Backend is not in my control and I cannot optimize the request body size. Apparently, a truncated-body request reaches server which doesn't response and hence the timeout. Is there a way to fix this issue. Note: If I replace OkHttp with Volley I do not see this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are facing timeout issue because of the response.
you can configure the `OkHttpClient`.

```
const val CONNECT_TIMEOUT = 10L
const val READ_TIMEOUT = 10L

val client = OkHttpClient.Builder().connectTimeout(CONNECT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .readTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MINUTES).build()
```

This will solve your problem. It will increase the time of your request and you will get response within the given time.

Comment: timeout is not the problem, server does not respond due to truncated request body sent to server